# My content DOES have a TabHost whose id is 'tabhost'

Tags: java, android

Ever since I restarted adb due to an error, I've have a certain activity crash which worked fine before. Now, when I click on that activity, I get this crash:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.minecraftultimate/com.example.minecraftultimate.SeedsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

But the thing is, that activity DOES have a tab host, with an id of tabhost. Here is my XML and activity class:

**activity_seeds.xml:**

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

And here is my **SeedsActivity.class**:

```
package com.example.minecraftultimate;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.widget.TabWidget;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class SeedsActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seeds);

        // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);


        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Vanilla");
        TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Biomes O' Plenty");
        TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Extra Biomes XL");

       // Set the Tab name and Activity
       // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected
        tab1.setIndicator("Vanilla");
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,VanillaSeedsActivity.class));

        tab2.setIndicator("Biomes O'P.");
        tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,BOPSeedsActivity.class));

        tab3.setIndicator("Extra Biomes XL");
        tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,ExtraBSeedsActivity.class));

        /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(tab3);

 }

}
```

Comment: TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); you are looking for tabhost inside android.R file. its not your xml file. you should be referring to your R file. it should be yourpackagename.R.id.tabhost

Comment: @sayed.jalil: No, the code here is correct.

Comment: "Ever since I restarted adb due to an error, I've have a certain activity crash which worked fine before" -- clean your project (e.g., Project > Clean in Eclipse) and try again. My guess is that your resources are out of sync with the pre-compiled Java code.

Comment: I am having the same problem and in my case, cleaning and building the project doesn't solve anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

or

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```

Just clean your project once and then run it may solve your problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem and in my case, cleaning and building the project doesn't solve anything. :(